# mongod.service file should be placed in /etc/systemd/ or /lib/systemd/ in ubuntu16

Tags: mongodb, systemd

I am confused regarding the problem i am having is that i have two system , in which in a system I have placed the mongod.service in **/etc/systemd/system** and in the second system I have placed it in **/lib/systemd/system** .

As both are currently showing the status as running.
but with the case of /etc

i check status by:-
**sudo systemctl status mongodb**
but this command does not work up with /lib/ case:
**service mongod status**.

can anyone let me understand what on earth is happening

Comment: well, i checked the status and status is showing by service mongod status. But the deal is that since i have not made mongod.service file in /etc/systemd/system/ , thus it's not showing the expected output , when i use systemctl

Answer (score 10):

Service files or unit files can be placed in any of the below paths

```
/etc/systemd/system/ - Prio 1
/run/systemd/system/ - Prio 2
/lib/systemd/system/ - Prio 3
/usr/lib/systemd/system/ - Prio 3
```

The order of precedence is as per priority as given above.

From official systemd documentation

> In addition to /etc/systemd/system, the drop-in ".d" directories for
>   system services can be placed in /usr/lib/systemd/system or
>   /run/systemd/system directories. Drop-in files in /etc take precedence
>   over those in /run which in turn take precedence over those in
>   /usr/lib. Drop-in files under any of these directories take precedence
>   over unit files wherever located. Multiple drop-in files with
>   different names are applied in lexicographic order, regardless of
>   which of the directories they reside in.

Systemctl status shall show the current status of unit files started from any of above paths.
Further you can use `systemctl list-unit-files` to see status of all unit files both enabled and disabled.

Read more [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Maybe it is worth to mention that you should place (customized) service files always into `/etc/systemd/system/` because if you put them in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` then they will be overwritten with default file when you install any updates.