# Why use /etc/systemd/system vs. /lib/systemd/system?

Tags: debian, systemctl, lintian

Company I work for develops Debian package files for our software.  Somewhere along the line the responsibility passed from one person to another and things started being done in a different way.

Previously we put our systemctl service files into /lib/systemd/system.  Now we are putting them into /etc/systemd/system.  It seems to work, which is great, but if you run lintian on the package, it considers this an error.

```
E: package: systemd-service-file-outside-lib etc/systemd/system/whatever.service
```

Few questions:

1. If this is considered an error, why does it work?
2. Is there a rationale for placing service files under /etc?
3. I know that in some cases, users might wish to customize the dependencies or a
   given service so (most likely) other things have completed before
   the service in question starts.
4. Based on (3), there is the possibility of bricking a customer's system if we suddenly change the file's location under /etc (assuming that they were marked as conf files, which at the moment they are not) to /lib and they had
   made any changes.
5. Any other insight into this?

Note, I've just read this: https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/3092/how-to-add-your-own-services-to-systemd-for-easier-management/

which seems to send the message that placing service files under /etc is something to be done at the discretion of the end user.

TIA,

DL

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic on [SO] and already has an answer on another [SE] site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206315/402870

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617153/mongod-service-file-should-be-placed-in-etc-systemd-or-lib-systemd-in-ubuntu/46672854#46672854